# How to define argument types for R functions?

Tags: r

I am writing an R function, and I want to make sure that the argument of my R function is of a certain class (eg, "matrix").

What is the best way to do this?

Say I have a function "foo" which computes the inverse of a matrix:

```
foo <- function(x)
{
   # I want to make sure x is of type "matrix"
   solve(x)
}
```

How can I say - as you might in C - `function(matrix x)` to denote that "`x` must be of type `matrix`, and if it isn't, then return an error"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can either check that it's a matrix with is.matrix or else convert it with as.matrix after the parameter is passed:

```
foo <- function(x)
{
   if(!is.matrix(x)) stop("x must be a matrix")
   # I want to make sure x is of type "matrix"
   solve(x)
}
```

Comment: Okay, cool. I was just completely oblivious to "is.matrix". Thanks!

Comment: Essentially every datatype has an *is* and *as* function.

Answer (score 16):

`stopifnot(is.matrix(x))`

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: besides

```
is.matrix(foo)
```

you can also test for

```
class(foo) == "matrix"
```

which also works for non-standard that do not have `is.foo()` functions.

Comment: Have to be careful here, since objects in R might have more than one class. So the code should read "matrix"%in%class(foo).