# Optim with multiple parameters - define function argument type

Tags: r, optimization, arguments

I want to minimize the first 11 (or any large number) parameters of a function, which takes 15 (or any number greater than 11 / the first number stated) parameters in total. The problem is that when I use the `optim` function with `par=c(...)` for the first 11 values, the function cannot be evaluated as it takes all 11 values for its first argument only. Is there any way to force each input argument to be a scalar / single number?

To be more specific:

```
fun_to_optim <- function(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,p1,p2,p3,p4)
{
   # I want to make sure m1 to m11 are single numbers and no vectors
   ...
}
# optimization
optim(par=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),fn=fun_to_optim,p1=data,p2=opt,p3=data,p4=1)
```

Trying to run this code always ends with the error message:  **Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "m1" is missing, with no default.** By printing out the arguments, I figured that the function assumes that all values from `par` are for the input variable `m1`. So `m1` is taken to be a vector with the initial values given through `par`.

Please note: I am aware of the possibility to simply put the first 11 parameters into a vector (let's say `para_to_optim`) and then call the `optim` function as I did. However, I explicitly do not want to do this because I need to optimize the parameters iteratively, i.e. starting with just 1 parameter and ending will all 11. Writing the function 11 times with different input argument structures seems a bit inefficient.

I have already checked similar post for function arguments such as [Forcing specific data types as arguments to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139778/forcing-specific-data-types-as-arguments-to-a-function) and [How to define argument types for R functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745514/how-to-define-argument-types-for-r-functions), but it would not be possible in my case to check the type of the argument within the function and wrapper or S3 classes are also kind of problematic. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: So when you say optimize just one parameter are you just treating the other parameters as fixed values that you specify?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would start with optimizing `m1`and keep all of the other m's fixed until up to the point where I want to optimize all of them, so from `m1`to `m11`.

Comment: So I take it just letting optim do it's own thing on your 11 parameters isn't working for some reason?

Comment: Correct, the `optim` function is not working as it takes the initial values for the 11 parameters (provided by `par=c(...)`) as the initial value for just the first function input `m1`.

Comment: Right but I'm asking why wrapping your function so that it provides the 11 parameters as a vector and then letting optim do it's own thing to optimize over the entire parameter space is something you don't want to do

Comment: Like are you opposed to using `f <- function(m, ...){fun_to_optim <- function(m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4], m[5], m[6], m[7], m[8], m[9], m[10], m[11], ...)}` so that optim will just try to optimize over all 11 parameters simultaneously as would typically be done.  Is there a reason you're set on maximizing one at a time?

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. I initially implemented it like that, i.e. letting `optim` simultaneously optimize all of the 11 parameters. However, there are some problems with the convergence / it simply does not converge or is highly dependent on the initial parameter values. Thus, I though it might be helpful to only iteratively increase the complexity of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried changing the method used? Add something like method="BFGS" to your call to optim.

Comment: Yes, I tried all relevant methods from `optim` for this problem, i.e. "Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG".